# python pandas, merge based on date and time

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking a for efficent way to merge 2 tables based on Date value.
I'd like to take a records from Table1, and then find all records in table2 that occured in 24hour window after the event from table1 happend.

For example in tables bellow:

```
Event123 from table1 should have 
Event-table2_1 
Event-table2_2 
but not Event-table2_3
```

since it happend after 24 hours passed.

```
table1:
Date - Time - Event
10/10/2018 - 10:00 - Event123

table2
Date - Time - Event
10/10/2018 - 12:00 - Event-table2_1
11/10/2018 - 11:30 - Event-table2_2
11/10/2018 - 12:30 - Event-table2_3
3/8/20018 - 15:00 - Event1234
5/9/20018 - 12:00 - Event12345
1/4/20018 - 13:00 - Event12346
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I can answer my own questions or should I edit my question.
So I found a solution, which might not be the best and fastest, but it does the job.

I created 2 new columns, start_date and end_date. Based on parameter time_delta I update both of those columns. and then just used sql statement

```
table1.to_sql('mo_no_aspekti', conn, index=False)
table1.to_sql('potresi_mag7', conn, index=False)
sql = '''select * from table 1pm, table2 ap WHERE ap.DateTime >= pm.DateTime12_min AND ap.DateTime <= pm.DateTime12_max '''
```